# Getting error GameObject.GetComponent() in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, observer-pattern

I am using this [tutorial](https://www.habrador.com/tutorials/programming-patterns/19-spatial-partition-pattern/) to develop an observer pattern for my game in unity. Here is the `Observer` class:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 namespace ObserverPattern
 {
     //Wants to know when another object does something interesting 
     public abstract class Observer 
     {
         public abstract void OnNotify();
     }

     public class Box : Observer
     {
         //The box gameobject which will do something
         GameObject boxObj;
         //What will happen when this box gets an event
         BoxEvents boxEvent;

         public Box(GameObject boxObj, BoxEvents boxEvent)
         {
             this.boxObj = boxObj;
             this.boxEvent = boxEvent;
         }

         //What the box will do if the event fits it (will always fit but you will probably change that on your own)
         public override void OnNotify()
         {
             Jump(boxEvent.GetJumpForce());
         }

         //The box will always jump in this case
         void Jump(float jumpForce)
         {
             //If the box is close to the ground
             if (boxObj.transform.position.y < 0.55f)
             {
                 boxObj.GetComponent().AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

However, when I want to run this it gives me this error:

> error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'GameObject.GetComponent()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The error is on this line:

```
boxObj.GetComponent().AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
```

Is there any possible way so that I can fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the templated argument in your case

`boxObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);`

Comment: that (I would also prefer this) or pass it as paramter `GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))`